# Router Navigate Using CreateUrlTree

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, router

Assuming I have the following url:

`team/11/user/22`

how do I traverse to team ID but keeping user ID intact?

`team/22/user/22`

`this.router.createUrlTree(['../../team/22'], {relativeTo: this.route})` deletes the user parameters.

Comment: hello try this.router.createUrlTree(['/team', 22, 'user', 22]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps someone, try something like this:

```js
// import location
import {
  Location
} from '@angular/common';

updateUrl() {
  // or pass teamId&userId into func
  const queryParams = {
    teamId: this.teamId,
    userId: this.userId
  };
  const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([], {
    queryParams: queryParams,
    relativeTo: this.activeRoute,
    skipLocationChange: true
  });
  this.location.replaceState(urlTree.toString());
}
```

Comment: This is using queryParams, but that's not what the question was about.

Comment: @Razze interesting because OP didn’t mention he wasn’t using params.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) instead of routing? You would essentially do `localStorage.setItem('user', userId)` and then you can route to `team/11/user/` and do a `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('user'))`

Comment: it looks like overkill, as for each request (production apps usually have ton of requests) you will save in browser storage. At some point it will blown up, IMHO.

Comment: That's a good point. My solution is more for apps with a small number of routes or a limited number of pages that would need this. you wouldn't do this for every route if you didn't need to and you could add `localStorage.removeItem('user')` when you're done with it

Comment: More important than the browser storage in my opinion is the fact that this breaks the ability for someone to bookmark or send a link to a user in your application. It also breaks the ability to have multiple tabs open. It's not a good approach in my opinion.

Comment: As some mentioned, doing this has a lot of implications. It doesn't answer the question, but is more of a workaround.